# Azure Traffic Manager - DNS TTL being ignored

Tags: azure, dns, azure-traffic-manager

I've just configured Traffic Manager for two endpoints and have noticed the TTL is being set to 3600 (1 hour) even though on the configuration page for the Traffic Manager profile it has been set to 300(5 minutes).

I've verified this by looking at the local DNS records and also with NSLOOKUP, both indicate it's being set to an hour.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Seems to now have resolved itself and is reporting the correct 5 minute TTL via NSLookup.

Comment: Are you sure this has been resolved? I've set the value to 0 so that the traffic would always be routed through the traffic manager, but the browser seems to always cache it anyway. I have to wait for the dns cache to be automatically flushed (or forcefully) to be redirected.